# vkontakte tag should be renamed

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

Social network vkontakte.ru is called vk.com now, so its tag is no longer relevant. I've added a new tag, [vk](/questions/tagged/vk), to a few questions to let new questioners choose the right one. But @Charles said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17071744/how-to-design-the-vkontakte-share-button-to-look-like-the-facebook-one?noredirect=1#comment25020898_17071744) that this is not a good practice.

Is it possible to rename [vkontakte](/questions/tagged/vkontakte) to [vk](/questions/tagged/vk), and add [vkontakte](/questions/tagged/vkontakte) as a synonym to [vk](/questions/tagged/vk)?

Comment: Creating a new tag - `vk` - is a good idea I think. But two tags meaning the same shouldn't be on the same question. It's confusing.

Comment: @qben yes, you're right. That's why I'm asking to make `vkontakte` the synonym of `vk`. And, if it possible, rename all `vkontakte` tag entries to `vk`. It's difficult to do without moderators, because: 1) I have no rights 2) these tags are not so popular, so casting synonym vote is very long procedure.

Comment: I think this name is far too short to be effective for a tag. I'm not russian, so `vk` means nothing and says nothing about the tag itself.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII it means nothing for russians too. vk is just a senseless website name.

Comment: @Hast, what about `[vk.com]` then?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi it looks pretty ok now, but if you think [vk.com] would be better, I should agree with that. Anyway, thank you!